# Visual Studio Code - Java Type Hierarchy

Tags: java, visual-studio-code

Does Visual Studio Code have a display Java Type Hierarchy feature? For example, given an abstract method, I frequently want to find all the subclasses that implement it. Or given an interface, find all the classes that implement it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently (as of March 2020) the core extensions for Java support on Visual Studio Code do not display type hierarchy.

See this issue for progress. [1]

[1] https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-java-pack/issues/152